# executorService.shutdownNow() doesn't stop the thread

Tags: java, multithreading, scheduledexecutorservice

I have a scheduled Executor service setup like

```
class Test {
    private final ScheduledExecutorService executor;
    public Test() {
        executor = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor((runnable) -> {
            Thread thread = new Thread(runnable, this.getClass().getName());
            thread.setDaemon(true);
            return thread;
        });
        executor.scheduleWithFixedDelay(
            new TestRefreshTask(), 0, 50000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS
        );
    }

    private class TestRefreshTask implements Runnable {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //refresh some data
            refreshdata();
        }
    }

    public void close() {
        executor.shutdown();
        try {
            if(!executor.awaitTermination(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {
                executor.shutdownNow();
                executor.awaitTermination(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS));
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            //Retry to dispose task
            executor.shutdownNow();
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

To stop this thread I call the close method but often the thread doesn't stop. I am not sure what's wrong and if somehow I am supposed to handle the `InterruptedException` in my run() code.

Comment: "There are no guarantees beyond best-effort attempts to stop processing actively executing tasks. For example, typical implementations will cancel via Thread.interrupt(), **so any task that fails to respond to interrupts may never terminate.**" - from [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#shutdownNow--)

Comment: Also: You wait for termination 60 seconds. Do you happen to know how long the refreshdata takes in average?

Comment: What version of Java are you using?

Comment: @JohnVint i am using java 1.8. Refresh does a lot of stuff but normally it takes less than 60 seconds. Good point though. Because I am running this code on server as well as local. The one on the remote machine seems to be failing more often

Answer (score 3):

- Real solution below the line. This part only describes the pitfalls.

From the javadoc of `shutdownNow()`:

> There are no guarantees beyond best-effort attempts to stop processing actively executing tasks. For example, **typical implementations will cancel via Thread.interrupt**, so **any task that fails to respond to interrupts may never terminate**.

From experience, threads do indeed get interrupted, but according to this documentation even that is not guaranteed.

However, your task is not something you control yourself, it's private task created within `scheduleWithFixedDelay()`.

From the javadoc of `scheduleWithFixedDelay()`:

> If any execution of the task encounters an exception, subsequent executions are suppressed. **Otherwise, the task will only terminate via cancellation or termination of the executor.**

This means that `shutdownNow()` will not stop the thread. The cancellation part is a bit unclear to me since a `Runnable`, as opposed to a `Future`, does not have a `cancel()` method. The other reason a task will stop is termination of the executor, however the pool only terminates when the tasks stop.

---

The real solution lurks in this part from the javadoc of `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor`:

> By default, such a cancelled task is not automatically removed from the work queue until its delay elapses. While this enables further inspection and monitoring, it may also **cause unbounded retention of cancelled tasks**. To avoid this, set setRemoveOnCancelPolicy to true, which causes tasks to be immediately removed from the work queue at time of cancellation.

When you order the executor to stop, it sets the interrupted flag, and if it's a `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor`, removes the task if the `removeOnCancelPolicy` is true.

Solution:

- **Execute `executor.setRemoveOnCancelPolicy(true)` before submitting the schedule.**

[edit]:
Since you use the factory method, this is not possible to implement directly.

Make these changes:

- `private final ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor executor;`
- `executor = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(1, (runnable) -> {`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but in my case, I managed to interrupt the Thread by itself. When the main thread executes the `executor.shutdownNow()` it sends a signal for every Executor's thread consequently each thread are able to identify their state by `Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()`.

How I implemented:

```
    if (Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
      return;
    }
```

Comment: I'm doing this, and I don't see it working.